# Example of non random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Given that a random variable $X$ defined on a sample space which takes value on the real line is defined as the set of all outcomes such that $X(outcome)\le r$, with $r$ a real number, that belongs to the event space for every $r$, can you provide me with one example (or more) of a non-random variable? 
Please give an example that contradicts the part of the statement relative to the fact that the set belongs to the event space, because it is easy to show that a $X$ not defined on the sample space or that takes values outside the real number set is non-random by definition.
I could not use latex properly to write rigorously the definition, however is the definition of Mood, Introduction to the theory of Statistics.

Comment: Both Kavi Rama Murthy and John Gowers have provided excellent answers. I wanted to chime in to point out that it's not that these examples are "non-random"; it's that they're "not random variables." In this context, the words "random" and "variable" really can't be divorced from one another. What makes the functions provided in the answers not random variables is a matter of measure theory and technicality, but it will be hard to affix any intuitive notion of randomness to their broken qualities.

Answer (score 4):

$\Omega =\{0,1\}, \mathcal F=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}, X(0)=0,X(1)=1$ is an example since $(X=0) \notin \mathcal F$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some concerns about this example.

1) what does the sample space represent in this case?

2) If, for example, $r<-1$ and $X = 0$ then $X(0)$ is not lower or equal to $-1$, then this case would be the empty set $∅$ which belongs to the event space, and with a similar rationale for every $r$ one could prove that $X$ is a random variable. Why does $X = 0$ not belong to the event space? What is the rationale behind that statement?

Comment: I try to explain better my point: 
if $r<0, (ω:X(ω)≤r)=∅$, and the empty set belongs to the event space
if $0≤r<1, (ω:X(ω)≤r)=0$, and $0$ belongs to the event space (if not why it does not belong to the event space? $0$ could be in a coin toss the event "TAIL" for example, which is indeed part of the event space).
If $r≥1, (ω:X(ω)≤r)=Ω$, which belongs to the event space.
Then $X$ is a r.v. Where is the mistake in this rationale?

Comment: You cannot conclude that $X$ is  a random variable simply because $(X \leq r)$ is an event for some values of $r$. You can can conclude that $X$ is  a random variable only when this holds for **every** real number $r$.

Comment: As I showed above the statement holds for every real number, indeed if you put together the three inequalities ($r$ lower than zero, between 0 and 1 and higher than 1) you get the whole real line, hence in every cases $X()$ is a r. v. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kolmogorovwannabe For $r=0$ we have $(X\leq r)=\{0\}$ which is not in the the collection of events.

Comment: Now it is clearer! What could be an experiment associated to this example in terms, e. g., of flippinig a coin? In other words why the outcome $0$ taken singularly is not part of the event space? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Take any non-measurable set $A$ (so $A\in \mathcal P( \Omega )\setminus \mathcal F$) and let $X$ be the indicator function for $A$; i.e.:

$$
X(c) = \begin{cases}
1 & c\in A \\
0 & c \not\in A
\end{cases}
$$

Then the set of all outcomes $c$ such that $X(c)<0.5$ is the complement of $A$, which is non-measurable.

Answer (score 0):

The identity function $X$  on $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $X(r)=r$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$) is not a random variable 
for the set of outcomes (sample space) $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ and the set of events $\mathcal{F}=$ 
{all (at most) countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and their complements}.
 The peculiarity of this example is that, for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$, $(X=r)$ is an event, yet $(X<r)$ is not.
 So "randomness" of a given $X\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ depends on the choice of $\mathcal{F}$ which is theoretically 
limited only by the requirement that $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra.

To apply probability theory to a real-world situation, one has to choose (explicitly or implicitly) some 
probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ including a probability measure $P\colon \mathcal{F}\to P$  (assignment of probabilities to events),
the choice being based upon some real-world data.
 Hypothetically, a hard-hitting researcher of coin tossing could refuse to consider $(X=0)$ 
as an event with a prescribed probability, so they could come to $\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ 
(mathematically correct, but probably of little use in real-world applications).
 The same experiment of flipping a coin, yet another interpretation 
(an answer to Kolmogorovwannabe's comment on Kavi Rama Murthy's answer).